# How to draw database Table items onto a TableView using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, tableview, h2

Thank you all with the help so far in my project.

I've been looking at this for most of today, but have been unsuccessful in getting any helpful material.

My project is in Java/ JavaFx, Hibernate and H2. So far I can persist items into the database but I cant figure out how to go about pulling the data onto a TableView. I've gone as far as drawing the data onto `System.out.println` but nothing more.

***These are my classes:***

*This Class creates the database object, NewBeautifulKiwi:*

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "KIWI_TABLE")
public class NewBeautifulKiwi implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int KiwiId;
    private String Kiwi;

    public int getKiwiId() {
        return KiwiId;
    }

    public void setKiwiId(int KiwiId) {
        this.KiwiId = KiwiId;
    }

    public String getKiwi() {
        return Kiwi;
    }

    public void setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
        this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
    }
}
```

*This Class initialises the NewBeautifulKiwi, creating the database Tables and Prints the inserted data to screen:*

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "KIWI_TABLE")
public class NewBeautifulKiwi implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int KiwiId;
    private String Kiwi;

    public int getKiwiId() {
        return KiwiId;
    }

    public void setKiwiId(int KiwiId) {
        this.KiwiId = KiwiId;
    }

    public String getKiwi() {
        return Kiwi;
    }

    public void setKiwi(String Kiwi) {
        this.Kiwi = Kiwi;
    }
}
```

I'd like to have what's printed on screen displayed in a TableView.

Any help would be great. I will be grateful for any help I can get. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

i am creating table and column in **`scene builder`**

```
 @FXML
 private TableView<PoJoName> table;

 @FXML
 private TableColumn<PoJoName, Integer> col1;

 @FXML
 private TableColumn<PoJoName, String> col2;

 public ObservableList<PoJoName> data; 

@FXML
void initialize() 
{

  col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PoJoName,Integer>("id")); // here id is a variable name which is define in pojo.
  col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PoJoName,String>("name"));

    data  =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();        
    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session sess  =sf.openSession();        
    Query qee = sess.createQuery("from PoJoName");
    Iterator ite  =qee.iterate();
    while(ite.hasNext())
    {
        PoJoName obj = (PoJoName)ite.next();    

        data.add(obj);           
    }        
    table.setItems(data);

}
```

Comment: Excellent example, and using `PoJoName` (vice the name of the OP's class) made it more widely applicable. +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a data model for `TableView`.

Read section "*Defining the Data Model*" here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm